# Android: Class in source code not found

Tags: java, android, reflection, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to access the [PhoneInterfaceManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/e411fca18119991bd4145cdfb13bce899d8c694d/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java) on android.
As it is not part of the sdk, I need to use reflection. (I know I shouldn't do this, but as far as I know there is no other way).
The full name of the class is "com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager".

Now when I run this code...

```
Object getPhoneInterfaceManager() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    return Class.forName("com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager");
}
```

...I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.phone.PhoneInterfaceManager

Note:
I checked the [grep repository](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java#PhoneInterfaceManager) (which I find to be more reliable sometimes) and noticed that while the package for classes which worked with reflection were in the project "com.google.android / android", this class was to be found in "com.google.android / android-**apps** ". I don't know if this might mean something, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It fails running it on emulator or in a physical device? Are you targeting the same API Level both on your code and the emulator/device?

Comment: @elefasGR, I am running the app on a physical device running API Level 22 (Lollipop 5.1) and have set both the min sdk and target sdk version to 22.